Error: ValueError: Must provide at least one structure
During executing below code:
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory=r'./train/',
    target_size=(224, 224),
    classes=['hot_dog','not_hot_dog'],
    class_mode='categorical',
    batch_size=batch_size,
    shuffle=True,
    seed=42)

valid_generator = valid_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory=r'./test/',
    target_size=(224, 224),
    classes=['hot_dog','not_hot_dog'],
    class_mode='categorical',
    batch_size=batch_size,
    shuffle=True,
    seed=42)

model.fit(train_generator, steps_per_epoch=15,
                    epochs=16, validation_data=valid_generator,
                    validation_steps=15)

I have an error
ValueError: Must provide at least one structure
Also there is message like below, so I assume it does not see images in the folders
Found 0 images belonging to 2 classes.

I tried to change directory path to
directory=./train/'
or
directory=/train/'
but it did not help. Folders are placed where the python file with code. I also found advise that there must be at least 8 images but in those folders there are hundreds so this is not the case.
I added subset tagging intro training and vaidation and this is also not a case. The same error. All images are dowloaded from kaggle as completed dataset

I apologize for bothering. I found the issue. The problem was with filepath and space which I did not notice.
